# How do I update a list of functions without having to create another object?

Tags: r, list

Like the title said, I want to update a list of functions without having to create another object.
I have a this code:

```
add.filter <- function(filters.list, ..., after) {
  filters.list <- append(filters.list, ..., after={{after}})
  filters.list <<- filters.list
}

filters.list <- list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
add.filter(filters.list, "d", after = 2)


filters.list
$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] "d"

$c
[1] 3
```

This work fine but I want the function add.filter to be able to work with a list of functions.

For example if :

```
filters.list <- list(function(x) replace(x, x == 3 , 300),
                     function(x) replace(x, x == "l" , 400)
                  )
```

How can I make the function add.filters() to work, if the arguments will be:

```
add.filter(filters.list, function(x) replace(x, x == 300 , 5000), after = 1)
```

The output I want for add.filters() will be something like:

```
filters.list
[[1]]
function(x) replace(x, x == 3 , 300)

[[2]]
function(x) replace(x, x == 300 , 5000)

[[3]]
function(x) replace(x, x == "l" , 400)
```

In summary I want to create an add.filters function that adds functions to an existing list of functions without having to create a new list. I want the original list to be updated with the new function(filter) added.
I want something like this to work :

```
add.filter <- function(filters.list, ..., after) {
              filters.list <- append(filters.list, ..., after={{after}})
              filters.list <<- filters.list
 }

g<-list(function(x) replace(x, x == 3 , 300),
        function(x) replace(x, x == "l" , 400)
)


add.filter(g, function(x) replace(x, x == 300 , 5000), after = 1)


g
[[1]]
function(x) replace(x, x == 3 , 300)

[[2]]
function(x) replace(x, x == "l" , 400)` 

this don't work well, so the question is how do I make the function add.filter to go for this type of list.

Thanks a lot
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? The original code already works, why do you not want to use it? That said, doing it this way is strongly discouraged. Instead of modifying a global variable, the conventional way in R is to return the modified list (or otherwise to use R6 objects). Furthermore, your code probably doesn't do what you think it does, since the `{{after}}` in your code has no effect: it's the same as if you had written `after`.

Comment: If I run this  `add.filter <- function(filters.list, ..., after) {
 filters.list <- append(filters.list, ..., after={{after}})
filters.list <<- filters.list
 }
> g<-list(function(x) replace(x, x == 3 , 300),
        function(x) replace(x, x == "l" , 400)

                   )
 add.filter(g, function(x) replace(x, x == 300 , 5000), after = 1)
g
[[1]]
function(x) replace(x, x == 3 , 300)

[[2]]
function(x) replace(x, x == "l" , 400)` this don't work well, so the question is how do I make the function go for this type of list

Comment: Your comment is pretty unreadable, please edit your question instead. That said, your comment seems to say that your list is unchanged after calling `add.filter` but you are looking at the wrong list! You are printing `g`. You should be checking `filters.list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if all you want to achieve is to not reassign the output of `add.filter()`. In that case we can capture the name of your input object with `deparse(substitute())` and use this in `assign()`. Further your function should have an `env` argument which defaults to the `parent.frame()` but which you can also overwrite. Be careful with this function in will overwrite its input object.

```r
add.filter <- function(filters.list, ..., after, env = parent.frame()) {
  obj_nm <- deparse(substitute(filters.list))
  out <- append(filters.list, ..., after = after)
  assign(obj_nm, out, envir = env)
}

filters.list <- list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
add.filter(filters.list, "d", after = 2)

filters.list
#> $a
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "d"
#> 
#> $c
#> [1] 3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: It's perfect, it's exactly what I wanted, you’re great thanks a lot!

Comment: @anria Please heed my original comment though: **this is a bad way of doing this** in almost all cases. You are breaking R's computational model by modifying the caller's data instead of returning it. — It seems that you come from a different programming language and are trying to force the other language's model onto R's semantics. Doing this is guaranteed to cause issues.

Comment: @anria: Konrad’s comment holds especially true if you are working with other useRs which will not expect a function to reassign an object in the caller environment. There are special cases in R where this is happening. For example with  `data.table` we have functions that modify a `data.table` in place. Also environments in R are mutables and can change without actually be reassigned. If you want to use the function above, even just for yourself, its probably a good idea to add a message that the input object has been changed.